# Velo by Wix, JSON data in repeater

Tags: arrays, json, backend, velo

I'm trying to get the temperature of each hour from this website: `https://www.smhi.se/vader/prognoser/ortsprognoser/q/Stockholm/2673730`

I'm getting the data from `https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16/lat/58/data.json`. The "t" object is the temperature.

The problem I have is displaying the data for each hour in the repeater.

Here is my backend-code:

```
import { getJSON } from 'wix-fetch';

export async function getWeather() {

    try {
        const response = await getJSON('https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16/lat/58/data.json');

        console.log(response)  // all data

        const tempData = response.timeSeries[0].parameters[10].values[0];

        return tempData // Only returns "t" - temperature

    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }

}
```

The backend part works, however the frontend doesn't.

```
import { getWeather } from 'backend/getSMHI.jsw'

$w.onReady(function () {
    (

        getWeather().then(weatherInfo => {

            $w('#weatherRepeater').onItemReady(($item, itemData, index) => {

                if (index > 6) {
                    $item('#tempText').text = itemData.timeSeries[index].parameters[1].values[0];   
                    
                } else if (index === 6) {
                    $item('#tempText').text = itemData.timeSeries[index].parameters[0].values[0];

                } else {
                    $item('#tempText').text = itemData.timeSeries[index].parameters[10].values[0];
                } // The parameters number for "t" changes depending on the index
            })
            $w('#weatherRepeater').data = weatherInfo;
        })
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are at least a couple of issues here.

First, you are retrieving a single number from the API and trying to put that in a repeater. From the description of what you're trying to do, it would seem that you mean to be retrieving a list of numbers, probably as an array. You probably want to do some filtering and/or mapping on the response data instead of directly accessing a single value.

Second, the data you send to a repeater must be in the proper format. Namely, it must be an array of objects, where each object has a unique `_id` property value (as a string). You are not doing that here. You are simply assigning it a number.

Third, and this is just an efficiency thing, you don't need to define the `onItemReady` inside the `then()`. Not that it will really make much of a difference here.